# browser call - Twilio.js in Struts2 (Java)

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api

New to Struts2 and Twilio.js (api sdk) here needing guidance.

I have double checked my twilio credentials, created access token and got it accepted on my browser, "[Device]: Stream is ready" on the console log. When I try to dial a number using the Twilio.Device.connect(~), console log shows {code: 31002, message: "Connection Declined", connection: a}. I don't know what to look for on the logs. I have setup the voice URL of TwiML app on the twilio account and test connection with ngrok https.

```
//ACTIVATE CALL START
            var connection = null;
            $("#activate-calls").click(function(){

                $("#answer").hide();
                $("#hangup").hide();
                $("#reject").hide();

                $.getJSON('activateCalls').done(

                        function (data) {
                             // log('Got a token.');
                              console.log('Token: ' + data.data.token);

                              // Setup Twilio.Device
                              Twilio.Device.setup(data.data.token, {debug: true});
                              Twilio.Device.ready(function (device) {
                                    $("#log").text("Ready");
                                });
                              Twilio.Device.error(function (error) {
                                    $("#log").text("Error: " + error.message);
                                });
                              Twilio.Device.connect(function (conn) {

                                    $("#log").text("Successfully established call");
                                    $("#call").hide();
                                    $("#reject").hide();
                                    $("#hangup").show();

                                });
                              Twilio.Device.disconnect(function (conn) {
                                    $("#log").text("Call ended. Ready for new incoming/ outgoing calls.");
                                    $("#hangup").hide();
                                    $("#call").show();
                                });


                                Twilio.Device.incoming(function(conn) {
                                    // Set the reference to the current
                                    // connection when we receive an
                                    // incoming call
                                    alert("ringring");
                                    connection = conn;
                                    $("#log").text("Incoming call from " + conn.parameters.From);
                                    $("#answer").show();
                                    $("#call").hide();
                                    $("#reject").show();

                                    // Clear the reference to the
                                    // connection when disconnected.
                                    connection.disconnect(function() {
                                        connection = null;
                                    })
                                });

                                Twilio.Device.cancel(function(conn) {
                                    $("#log").text("Ready");
                                    $("#answer").hide();
                                    $("#reject").hide();
                                    $("#call").show();
                                });
                                $("#reject").click(function() {
                                    $("#log").text("Incoming call is rejected. Ready for new incoming/ outgoing calls.");
                                    connection.reject();
                                    $("#answer").hide();
                                    $("#reject").hide();
                                    $("#call").show();


                                });

                                $("#answer").click(function() {
                                    // If there's no pending connection,
                                    // there's nothing to do.
                                    if (!connection) { return; }

                                    // Update the interface
                                    $("#answer").hide();
                                    $("#call").show();
                                    $("#log").text("Call accepted");

                                    // Accept the current connection.
                                    connection.accept();
                                });

                                $("#call").click(function() {
                                    // get the phone number to connect the call to
                                    params = {"PhoneNumber": $("#number").val()};
                                    Twilio.Device.connect(params);
                                });

                                $("#hangup").click(function() {
                                    Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
                                    $("#log").text("Ready");
                                });





                        }



                );


            });


            //ACTIVATE CALL END
```

The jsp/html looks like this..

```
<div align="center">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon"><img src="https://www.twilio.com/bundles/favicons/img/Twilio_16.png" /></div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="number" name="number">
                    </div>

                    <button class="btn btn-success" id="answer">Accept</button>

                    <button class="btn btn-success" id="call">Call</button>

                    <button class="btn btn-danger" id="hangup">Hangup</button>

                    <button class="btn btn-danger" id="reject">Reject</button>


                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="log" class="alert-info" style="width: 347px; font-size: large;"></div>
            </div>
```

My action class on activeCalls to create token is this:

```
public String execute(){

    logger.debug("MCI> ActivateCallsAction.execute");

    String identity = "johnny";

    List<Scope> scopes = new ArrayList<>();
    scopes.add(new IncomingClientScope(identity));
    scopes.add(new OutgoingClientScope.Builder(APP_SID).build());


    Jwt jwt = new ClientCapability.Builder(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN).scopes(scopes).build();

    String token = jwt.toJwt();
    logger.debug("token: " + token);

    HashMap<String, String> json = new HashMap<>();
    json.put("identity", identity);
    json.put("token", token);
    data = json;

    logger.debug(json.get("token") + "-" + json.get("identity"));



    return "success";
}
```

I can post the complete error from the console logs if needed. TIA!

Comment: Have you checked the [Twilio debugger in your Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/debugger)? Are there any messages there?

Comment: The action code doesn't work without a configuration.